# Should "each" always be paired with a singular verb, even when a 'singular noun' and [each + partitive] are paired?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, collective-nouns, singular-they, singular-subject-and-verb

I know that normally singular verbs are to be used with "each", but what if an individual and 'each' + a partitive involving a collective noun, such as "family", is spoken of, and "their" is used in referring to the individuals involved?

For example, is this correct:

> Both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family has chosen to
> spend their life eating chocolate, and has been offically registered
> as a dyed-in-the-wool chocolate lover.
>
> (has, their life, has, as a ... lover)

Or this:

> Both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family have chosen to spend their lives eating chocolate, and have been offically registered as dyed-in-the-wool chocolate lovers.

> (have, their lives, have, as ... lovers)

I could get rid of the "their" by replacing it with "his or her," perhaps (depending on current gender usage), but it seems/sounds awkward ("has chosen to spend his or her life").

If all the people being spoken of were male, it could be "his life" or "her life," but as there is a mixture of genders involved, "their life" is the only logical usage, right?

Comment: You can't say "both Tinkerbella and each" unless "Tinkerbella" is somehow the plural of "Tinkerbell". "Both" means two.

Comment: ... Can one of us rephrase that, @Peter, to 'both A and B' requires that A and B both be in singular form or both be in plural form? (Though I'm still working on 'both clothes and furniture', plural-form non-count and singular-form non-count. 'They need both clothes and furniture' doesn't raise my hackles. Perhaps  'both A and B' requires that A and B both be (a) singular-form count-nouns (/proper nouns), (b) plural-form count-nouns (/proper nouns), or (c) non-count nouns'?)

Comment: @Edwin's right; my comment was too broad. You can combine singular and plural forms using *both* as long as there are conceptually two things. So you could say: "both our coffee and our sandwiches," but you can't say "both the sheriff and the three deputies." And I don't see how "Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family" could be categorized conceptually as  two things.

Comment: Deeper and deeper.

Comment: @PeterShor See "Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family"  categorized as "she and they".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family has chosen to spend their life eating chocolate,

This is incorrect.

1. **Both**, as a subject, governs a plural verb.
2. "Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family" is the cataphoric referent of "both".
3. The pronoun for the NP "Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family" is "they", which also governs a plural verb.

Without "both" the sentence has two forms:

4.Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family **have** chosen to spend **their** life eating chocolate,

5.Tinkerbella - and each member of the McGorkle family - **has** chosen to spend **her** life eating chocolate,

If the subject of the sentence were "Each member of the McGorkle family" -then "Each member of the McGorkle family **has** chosen to spend **their** (singular) or **his/her** life eating chocolate,"

"Each" is partitive and takes a singular verb.

Comment: I wonder what function you assign to "Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family". Is it an appositive, in apposition to "both"? Or something else?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan ""Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family" is the cataphoric referent of "both".

Comment: "Because he was hungry, John ate dinner." <-- "John" is the cataphoric referent of "he", but that is not its function; it is a subject. So I'm wondering about the function you assign to that phrase.

Comment: In constructions where **both** precedes coordinated elements which are nouns or noun phrases (e.g. ‘both her mother and her father came to visit’), both could be regarded as a determiner (or "predeterminer") modifying the two noun phrases (or a simple adjective). However, I do not think it is necessary to go to this length. Both requires a referent and "pronoun" seems favourite.

Comment: I ask because your answer doesn't make sense to me. You say in point #1 that "both" is a subject, but now you say that it is "a determiner (or "predeterminer") . . . or a simple adjective". However, those normally don't function as subjects (with a few exceptions--such as adnouns--none of which would apply here).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I qualified with  "However, I do not think it is necessary to go to this length. Both requires a referent and "pronoun" seems favourite."

Comment: OK, so I think you're saying that "both" is a pronoun. But I still don't know the function of "Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family". You've called it a referent, but referent isn't usually considered a function, as I mentioned above (with the "John" example).

Comment: "Both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family" is a noun phrase and the subject. But "Both" or "Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family" could take the role of subject. If it were "Both" then a referent would be needed.

Comment: Your answer says that "both" functions as subject, and now you say that the coordinated phrase is the subject, too. And then you suggest that either could be subject. I'll admit that I'm somewhat confused, but I'm prepared to let this issue rest at this point. Thank you for responding to my questions.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I was just about to suggest that you ask a question about "Both + NP and NP".

Answer (score 1):

When you use "and" you made it a plural subject regardless of other considerations.  Plural subjects take plural verbs.  For instance, [here](https://www.grammar.com/subject-verb-agreement-plural-subjects/), the first example is

> The critic and the author rarely agree.

Where both "critic" and "author" are singular.  Therefore the question of what effect "each" has is moot.

Answer (score 1):

You have a compound subject consisting of two components: "Tinkerbella" and "each member of the McGorkle family". Because the components are connected by "and", the subject should be construed as plural.<sup>1</sup> Therefore, the second sentence is correct.

Peter Shor (in a comment) objects to "both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family", claiming that "both" must refer to exactly two items. However, I have no problem with something like "both the Jets and the Sharks dance well". (There must be at least four items: at least two Jets and two Sharks.) I'm therefore OK with "both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family", although you may want to consider rewording, since some people clearly find that troublesome.

Note 1: There are some exceptions (such as "peanut butter and jelly"), but those wouldn't apply here.

Comment: 'Bacon and eggs / Peanut butter and jelly are both to be found on the next aisle.' Logical agreement is logical, taking the appropriate verb form in each individual example.  (For the sake of completeness.) // A serious problem is following << There must be at least four items: at least two Jets and two Sharks. [>1 + >1]>> with << I'm therefore OK with "both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family" >> [1 + >1].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't mean that "peanut butter and jelly" could never be plural, only that it could be singular. // Yes, the series in this sentence is 1 + >1, but my point is that "both" doesn't have to refer to exactly two items (at least in my opinion), which I think PS was suggesting. If you prefer, I could use another example, e.g. "I like both fudge and sprinkles on my ice cream."

Comment: 'There must be at least four items: at least two Jets and two Sharks.'means **one shouldn't** therefore be OK with "both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess that I wasn't very clear. I meant: 1) That particular phrase clearly includes at least 4 items. 2) I'm OK with using "both' with it. 3) Therefore, I'm OK using "both" with more than two items. Perhaps I'll replace it with another example.

Comment: I'm not happy at all with 'both Tinkerbella and each member of the McGorkle family' (1 + n). 'Both the Smith triplets and the Jones boys turned up' doesn't cause me the same hackle-raising reaction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, I suspect that it will differ from person to person. I'm not aware of any generally accepted "rule" for this issue.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Just curious: Are you OK with the "fudge and sprinkles" example? Or: "We manufacture items for both the export market and domestic customers"? I think that the partitive nature of "each" is a big part of issue.

Comment: Yes. It could be the noncount nature with the first, and perhaps also 'padding' with the second (which pairs probable non-count and count usages)..